# FXML Load exception

Tags: java, exception, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I got a problem that I absolutely can't solve on my own because I have just started using JAVA FX. 
I get a nasty javafx.fxml.LoadException: , but I have done exactly like a guide, but I cant get my Main to run. 
This is the the exception output:

```
apr 07, 2014 4:06:37 EM application.Main start
ALLVARLIG: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Jakob/Dropbox/java_kurser/Project%20Timeline/bin/application/LoginGUI.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,6]
Message: Bearbetningsinstruktionens målmatchning "[xX][mM][lL]" är inte tillåten.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

LoginController.java

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="loginButton"
    private Button loginButton; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="newUserButton"
    private Button newUserButton; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="passwordField"
    private PasswordField passwordField; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="usernameField"
    private TextField usernameField; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        assert loginButton != null : "fx:id=\"loginButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'LoginGUI.fxml'.";
        assert newUserButton != null : "fx:id=\"newUserButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'LoginGUI.fxml'.";
        assert passwordField != null : "fx:id=\"passwordField\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'LoginGUI.fxml'.";
        assert usernameField != null : "fx:id=\"usernameField\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'LoginGUI.fxml'.";


        //The button event for the login button
        loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent e)   {
                System.out.println("This button works");
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

LoginGUI.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?scenebuilder-background-color 0x008effff?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="LoginController">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="loginButton" cancelButton="false" contentDisplay="CENTER" defaultButton="true" layoutX="254.0" layoutY="263.0" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="1.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Login" underline="false">
      <font>
        <Font size="14.0" fx:id="x1" />
      </font>
    </Button>
    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="206.0" prefHeight="23.000099999997474" prefWidth="118.0" promptText="Password" />
    <TextField fx:id="usernameField" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="166.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="118.0" promptText="Username" />
    <Label layoutX="248.0" layoutY="98.0" prefHeight="35.000099999997474" prefWidth="105.0" text="Welcome">
      <font>
        <Font size="22.0" />
      </font>
    </Label>
    <Button id="loginButton" fx:id="newUserButton" cancelButton="false" contentDisplay="CENTER" defaultButton="true" font="$x1" layoutX="254.0" layoutY="313.0" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="1.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="New User" underline="false" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and Main.java

```
package application;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("LoginGUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Bluerift Timeline");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please translate: Bearbetningsinstruktionens målmatchning "[xX][mM][lL]" är inte tillåten.

Comment: The processing instructions goal match........ is not allowed.
And in the beginning: ALLVARLIG: null = SERIOUS : null

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but the main method is unusual. You can just do `launch(args);`. Whatever you do, though, passing in a null reference for the args array is a pretty bad idea. `Application.launch(Main.class, new String[0]);` would be much safer if you wanted (for some reason) to force it to ignore command line arguments.

Comment: @James_D Oh you are an angel ;) Thanks. I wrote as you suggested with new String[0] and now it launched! :D :D Thanks again :D Now i know that for sure and hopefully wont do the same mistake again.

Comment: Ah Freaking Java fx. I hate it now :( Now its the same problem as before, but i have it exactly like i had it yesterday when it worked. I dont know what i will do. throw out my computer maybe

Comment: check your IDE settings and try to rebuild the project, delete the production files etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is in source

So, you've got to change it to a proper one

So do that, edit the source of the fxml file here

```
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("LoginGUI.fxml"));
```

with this one

```
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/packagename/LoginGUI.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem today and for those who may have it and (like me) are looking for an answer for that:

You may **have changed any component Id** on your Controller file and **forgot to update the Id** on sceneBuilder (or FXML file)[or Vice-Versa], so the Controller can't link the component on View file.

For Exemple:
(On Controller file)

```
@FXML
Button btnName1
```

(On FXML file or SceneBuilder)

```
fx:id="btnName_1"
```

:-)

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this issue too. I found that I did not add the package name to the controller name given in the FXML file; I initially just added the Controller class name.
 For example: if my controller class is under `com.stackoverflow.gui` package and the name of my controller class is `LoginController`. The FXML file should have `com.stackoverflow.gui.LoginController` and not just `LoginController`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by changing the file: "module-info.java".

```
module your_project_name {     
   requires javafx.controls;     
   requires javafx.fxml;     
   opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;     
   exports gui to javafx.fxml;     
   opens gui to javafx.fxml; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).