# I have problem with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

[it's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6uxj.jpg) I'm not good at programming but I try to learn. I am learning how to use javaFx. In this case I want to implement 4 operations: add, subtract, multiply and divide. When I was using only one it worked for me I am new to the Starck overflow community. I always check when I have doubts. But I did not find a solution to my problem. It would be very helpful if you support me.
If you like me to share the folder. They explain to me how it would be very helpful.
Also my english's not good but i'm learning to

Comment: Please put the error, including the full stack trace, in your question. Also add the fxml file which the error message tells you contains the problem

Comment: do some research to learn, when stuck with a concrete problem come back with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this post on InvocationTargetException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/14921272)

[See the Oracle Documentation on RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

[See this post on javafx.fxml.LoadException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23894982/14921272)

**As noted in the comments, the *[stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/14921272)*, in your case the red error text, tells you one of the problems: ** "Error resolving onAction = '$handleResta', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script".

The comments are also asking for the file which contains the error, in order to help you more fully; We've identified that `onAction = '#handleResta'` is a problem problem, but we can't tell what about `#handleResta` is creating the error until you post this file:

```
/C:Users/Usuario/Downloads/Proy/build/classes/mvvm/FXMLVista.fxml:14
```

Comment: Ty so much for helping me. I was finding how use Scene Builder and some Examples. The problem was that when saving directly from Escene builder. The override is not automatically generated above each action.  Like this                                                                     @FXML
    void handleResta(ActionEvent event) {
    }